# SQL subqueries calculating home winning percentage

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to calculate the home winning percentage for an athletic team and keep receiving 100 percent. Essentially I want to count the number of home wins divided by the number of home games. Please see below for the code that I have. Thank you for the help!

```
select (Count(r.WinLoss)*100)/Count(h.Location) As 'Winning Percentage'
From Result r,
     (select Location
      From Game g
      Where Location= 'Home') h
Where Winloss = 'Win';
```

Comment: You need a JOIN condition.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to skin this cat, but this should get you going.

```
SELECT
  ( 100 * (SELECT Count(id) FROM WinLoss WHERE WinLoss LIKE 'Win' AND Location LIKE 'Home')
  / CONVERT(decimal(4,2),(SELECT Count(id) FROM WinLoss WHERE Location LIKE 'Home'))) AS 'Home Win %'
```